# Gui Text issue not appearing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently having a problem with Gui Text in unity 5. What I am trying to get is the score to appear on the screen. The scoring system works since I have a Debug.Log output that tells me it works, however the Gui Text isn't showing up but is if I simply type it into the text box.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour {

    public static int myScore;
    public bool allowScore = false;
    public GUIText myText;

    //only allows score to start when first object has passed player object
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collisionObject) {
    allowScore = true;
    }

    //add 1 to score every switch
    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0) && allowScore == true) {
            myScore = myScore + 1;
            Debug.Log ("My score is " + myScore + " point(s)");
        }

        //GUI text for screen
        myText.text = "Score: " + myScore.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless this is a typo, you have a line of code that has two equal signs:

```
myText.text = "Score: " = myScore.ToString();
```

What I am guessing you are trying to do is have it say Score: and then display the score. To do this just change the second equal to plus.

```
myText.text = "Score: " + myScore.ToString();
```

Also just one helpful hint, on the line of code that says `myScore = myScore + 1;`, you can simply do `myScore++;`, and if you wish to add more than one at somepoint you can say `myScore += amountToAdd`. The `+=` means that you want it to be equal to itself plus the other side of the equation, the `++` just means add 1 to it.
*Edit: Response to comment*
NullReferenceExceptions occur when you try assigning a value to a variable that is un-assigned in the system. And as seeing above, in your code you declare the variable `public GUIText myText` and then later you try altering this objects text, however, nowhere in your code do you say what `myText` is equal to. So when you are calling `myText.text` it is trying to set the text of a non existent(null) variable. To fix this, in Unity once you have exited the code, in the inspector you will be able to see the code attached to your object. In that script component you will see the variable `myText`, drag a GameObject with a GUIText component from your hierarchy into that slot.
[image: My image...]

Comment: Ah yes that was a typo I thought I had updated the code but obviously  not. The code runs but nothing shows. In the console it said unnassigned reference exception, variable mytext of score has not been assigned. And I really have no idea what they mean by that. Any ideas ?

Comment: Fabulous. I added the game Object that was using the script to the text in the inspector and it works perfectly now. I didn't realise I needed to apply it manually to the same script on other objects but that was no problem. Thanks.

Comment: Nice every little helps :)